# Count Number Of Sub-Folders in VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I want to get number of sub-folders of a specific folder via VB script

```
strFolder = "D:\MainFolder\"
Count = strFolder.Subfolders
Echo count
```

Above code is just an example algorithm for my purpose code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprise:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFolder(".\").Subfolders.Count
>>
5
```

(you need a FSO in goFS, thou)